# How to interrelated the atributtes when the file is read? RandomAccessFile readingUTF();

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

Hi when I read the file with readUTF() method, the console output displays the atributtes separately. For example, I have this code:

```
public void grabarFichero(String clave, String nombre, String edad, String sueldo)
{
    int i;
    String datos[] = new String[4];
    datos[0] = clave;
    datos[1] = nombre;
    datos[2] = edad;
    datos[3] = sueldo;
    try
    {
        rafObj = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
        rafObj.seek(rafObj.length());
        for(i=0; i<datos.length; i++)
        {
            rafObj.writeUTF(datos[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void leerFichero()
{
    String clave, nombre, edad, sueldo;
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    try
    {
        rafObj = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
        rafObj.seek(0);
        rafObj.seek(0);
        while(rafObj.getFilePointer()<rafObj.length())
        {

            System.out.println(rafObj.readUTF());
        }
}
```

So, the output is this:

```
AF
Amaro
25
1500
LO
Bea
45
6258
```

It is essential to use RandomAccesFile class but the problem is that if I search ("clave: AF" for example) the program has to return "nombre: Amaro", "edad: 25" and "sueldo: 1500".
If I search ("clave: LO") the program has to return "nombre: Bea", "edad: 45" and "sueldo: 6258".

Comment: what was your question again?

Comment: I would like the atributtes were interrelated (Clave, Nombre, Edad, Sueldo) when I read the file.